# View local html/js contents in mobile safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I need to view some local (saved somewhere in the iPad) html / js contents with mobile Safari. By reading some threads it seems that the file:// protocol is disabled. Right?

If so, the solution I see is to install an app which turns the iPad into an http server (no need for support of php or anything else), load my contents there and access somehow them within the same device by `http://localhost/...` or `http://127.0.0.1/...` with mobile safari.
Is that actually possible? Can someone please suggest me a good web server app which possibly does not require jailbrake or other hacking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do what you want because in order for your application to be serving up HTTP requests to Mobile Safari, it would have to be running in the background, and there's no permissible background mode that covers this.

If you only need a one-time-only response immediately after running your application, then you could possibly use [`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a), although this might not be approved by Apple - it's difficult to predict their response to that.

If you are sure that you don't need this to go into the App Store, then you can get your application running in the background permanently by abusing one of the other background modes, such as pretending to be a VOIP app or media player.

Once you're running in the background, you can use [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer) to actually serve the files.

If you describe what you are trying to achieve, somebody might be able to suggest an alternative approach to using local files / Mobile Safari.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I need to do is to show some html5 interactive contents running on the iPad. The problem is that I will not have any internet connection while running the demo. I'm trying to find an easy solution which will not require creating a dedicate app. I could put my contents into my Android phone, install a web server there (like kWS), put contents there, activate the portable wifi feature and connect with the iPad there but I would keep it as last resort

Comment: Have you tried applications like [Offline Pages](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/offline-pages-offline-web/id364859644?mt=8)?  Alternatively, HTML 5 includes offline functionality you could use.  If you're going to create your own application, it would be far simpler to simply load your content into a `UIWebView` than switch out to Mobile Safari, you don't have to deal with the background process issue then.

Comment: Thanks again! The fact is that (as far as I've read) the UIWebView is based on an old version of webkit and I need full power, especially on the javascript engine side. That's why I'm thinking to use mobile safari for now. And I guess Offline pages is based on UIWebView too. If so, I think there is no other way out than using a second device as server for now... what do you think?

Comment: No, it uses the same version of WebKit as Mobile Safari, it's just missing a particular type of JavaScript optimisation.  I think you'd be nuts to go for the vastly more complicated approach without even trying the simple approach.

Comment: Ok, I'll follow your suggestion and see what happens (as soon as Apple delivers me the iPad I've just purchased :S ). Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Jim, I finally managed to create a simple app which loads local (resources) html into UIWebView. The HTML loaded is actually my demo and in the simulator performances are just fine. I don't know how simulator webview performances compare to real iPad, as I guess the simulator uiwebview is actually run by the hosting mac webkit and processor... still waiting apple to deliver my ipad...